# Cleaning room type data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to clean my data and there is a column named 'Room Type' and it has about 160-170 distinct values where it should only be 10 or 15. Most of it has data such as this, for example; a single room has been entered in different ways:

```
"Single room level 1"
"Single room level 2"
"Single room Street Side"
```

"Queen room level 1"
"Queen Room level 2"
"Ensuite Street Side"
"Ensuite Including Mini Bar"

I want to clear all the sub-Data like levels or street side, and I want my data set to display the rows like this:
"Single Room"
"Single Room"
"Single Room"
"Queen Room"
"Queen Room"
"Ensuite Room"
"Ensuite Room"

I want it this way so that it is easieer to use the groupby function and get the earnings based on each of these room types.
I apologize for not being clear.

Comment: Please update the question to show what you’ve tried/researched so far.  Have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding what is expected in a question.

Comment: @Nandu also please provide the exact specific output for those three rows. It's not clear exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Nandu is your main type i.e. "Single Room", "Queen Room" are always two worded and appear in the first of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more approach.

**Input**

```
id  room_type
1   Single room level 1
2   Single room level 2
3   Single room Street Side
4   Double room Street Side
```

**Code**

```
df['room_type']= np.where(df['room_type'].str.contains('Single'),'Single','Double')
```

**Output**

```
id  room_type
1   Single
2   Single
3   Single
4   Double
```

If you have 15 types of rooms, you can use `np.select` instead of `np.where`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this with an example

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'room_type': ["single", 'Single room', 'room', 'not a rooom']})
df['room_type'] = df['room_type'].apply(lambda room_type: 'Single Room' if re.search(r'single', room_type) else room_type)
```

The above will replace any value with **Single** in it.

Answer (score 0):

Another, slightly shorter solution:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'room_type': ["Single room level 1", "Single room level 2", 
                                 "Single room Street Side", "Double Room"]})
df.room_type.apply(lambda x: "Single Room" if "single" in x.lower() else x)
```

If your data is inconsistent then you probably could also have multiple capitalizations of the word "Single", and so you'd need to compare to the lowercase version of the word. You can simply check for whether "single" belongs to the string by using the `in` operator, as in `"single" in "single room"` and apply this function to the whole column.